# Dell force10 mxl 10/40gbe create trunk port

Tags: dell, force10

I have this task. I need to find the way how to configure a trunk in this switch for 3 VLANS 200,201 and 1(native) . I already read the guide. In this switches you need to activate the vlan and then change the port to switchport (layer 2) the you configure it the port inside the vlan.

interface vlan 200

tagged gi 0/3

exit

and that interface is already a trunk for vlan 200. I did the same with vlan 201 but with vlan 1 I dont have that option.

[image]

I dont have the untagged and tagged options. Also I dont see the ip routing option to alloq Vlan communication. How can I do it in this switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLAN 1 is the native VLAN, which means its traffic is untagged. That is fine for a trunk because it will be the only VLAN with untagged traffic.

You tag traffic on trunks so that the other end of the trunk can separate which frames belong to which VLANs. Having a single untagged (native) VLAN will work with this. It is only if you have multiple untagged VLANs on a trunk where you couldn't separate the frames into VLANs.

Comment: What if I want to use the VLAN 1 as native? can I do it?

Comment: Yes, the frames are just untagged. The other end of the link will be able to separate the native VLAN frames because they will be the only untagged frames.

Comment: But I cant configure it an ip address in the native VLAN. So basically I cant route traffic. I am asking these because my client want to use VLAN 1 as Native and use the existing ip address scheme.

Comment: The  `ip` command appears to be available in your image. Can't you use it?

Comment: Well i will try but I read that  you cannot add an Ip to the native vlan (default 1) in this force10.unless you cahnge the native vlan

Answer (score 1):

As a best practice, I like to define all "trunk" ports as hybrid ports in the Force10 terminology. In my opinion is more flexible, allow you to pass only the relevant VLAN taged and only one untagged.

Just a reminder, Force10 don't like to usee VLAN 1 for production purpose. I always use a fiction "vlan 2" as default VLAN.

Answering your question, try defining the port-channel as "portmode hybrid" and "switchport". About inter-vlan routing, it's enabled  when you assign and ip address to the interface vlan.

Answer (score 0):

Since a Native Vlan is untagged on all ports it should not matter which vlan id you use as the native vlan. The decision should be local to this device and you should not have to change existing configurations on neighboring switches.